# How to root a Yxtel G928? (Spreadtrum SC6820 chipset)

Tags: rooting

I've tried to find information on rooting a Yxtel G928.

[Specs listed here](http://mobilespecs.net/phone/Yxtel/Yxtel_G928.html): Spreadtrum SC6820 chipset; that site says it runs Android 2.3.6 but my phone says it's running Android 4.1. It's GSM and not locked to any network.

I can't find any reputable steps, just a few isolated forum posts on forums without any particular reputation for trustworthiness linking to zip files hosted on sites I wouldn't automatically trust.

Yxtel are a Chinese manufacturer who make low-end Android smartphones aimed at the developing world. Information is therefore relatively hard to find - if they have any guides of their own, I can't find them. I've read [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device?lq=1) and looked for info on xda-developers without success. - closest I can find is [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2445891) that seems to link to a solution for "Spreadtrum based phones" but I can't find what they mention on the links given.

I'd like to root to remove the bloat and to aid app testing.

---

I've tried using the [Kingo Root apk](https://root-apk.kingoapp.com/kingoroot-download.htm) but it fails with this message:

> ROOT FAILED
>
> ERROR CODE: 0x18A4FE

I've also tried Kingroot APK, and [Z4root from here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833953) but it just closes midway through the process and does nothing; iRoot (new version of vRoot) suggested on that thread [apparently is malicious](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/iroot-previously-vroot-safe-t2984822) and [installs a mystery additional app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/chinese-iroot-apk-superuser-apk-t2983083) not related to superuser permissions with protections against its removal. There's no "fastboot" on the recovery menu.

A few places recommend "Root With Restore" ([example](http://www.androidtablets.net/threads/root-many-of-your-chinese-androids-using-no-rom-image-using-pc.57340/)) not for this specific model but for ones like it - but I don't really want to run a zip full of `.bat` and `.exe` files on my computer without knowing what's in them.

Most of the 'standard' rooting methods seem to require downloading some phone-specific files that I can't find for this model.

Comment: use Vroot for pc its the best in rooting spresadrum phones using mocordroid 2.35.7. try to make sure that u using the usb cable for your smartphone

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try Framaroot [Here](https://www.framaroot.net)

Comment: Framaroot is a genuine rooting app, but it relies on kernel security vulnerabilities, so I can't say whether it will work on your phone.

Comment: Thanks! I've had a look at the list of supported devices and it's very comprehensive, but unforuntately doesn't seem to support Yxtel or Spreadtrum-based phones

Comment: @user568458 you can also try this thread  ->  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2165554 it's something about rooting spreadtrum devices

Comment: Yeah I've been trying those options. First doesn't work, second is apparently full of malware according to this threat http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/iroot-previously-vroot-safe-t2984822

Comment: @user568458 did you try SuperSU premium version ?

Comment: According to that xda thread SuperSU doesn't work with spreadtrum